# Add styling to a custom menu item in TinyMCE 5

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, styling, tinymce-5

I want to add some styling to a custom menu item in TinyMCE 5. Can I add a CSS class to the item or can I add some inline styles?

Here is a fiddle with the basic code to create a custom menu item - because it does not seem to work here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bhdwtp3m/

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#mytextarea',
  menu: {
        custom: { title: 'Custom Menu', items: 'undo redo myCustomMenuItem' }
    },
    menubar: "file | edit | custom",
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.ui.registry.addMenuItem('myCustomMenuItem', {
            type: 'menuitem',
            text: 'Custom menu item',
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<textarea id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the editor?

Comment: @m4n0 - I want to add a menu item that adds a custom HTML fragment. It would be nice if I kan give that menu item some custom styling like color and background.

Comment: Okay, which part do you want to style? The button or the sub menu items? The code generates an ID so you can make use of that to target the classes. I can answer based on your preference.

Comment: I need to style menu items and sub-menu items. I do not see any unique identifier on them. If I could add a CSS classname or some HTML in the label, that would be awesome.

Comment: @m4n0 - do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Did you try this? https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-css-and-custom-styles/

Comment: @m4n0 - Thanks for the link, but this is not exactly what I was looking for. That is about styling the editor not specific menu items.

Comment: Don't you just have to use the custom menu item selectors with that method?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but there is no supported way to style individual toolbar buttons in TinyMCE by means of adding classes or IDs. The reason is in the nature of CSS – it's right there in the name: cascading... If the TinyMCE CSS changes, it will bleed into any third party UI, possibly breaking it. Sometimes we also need to change the DOM structure of UI components.

While many developers know exactly how handle this, there are many that will hang themselves with all the rope given to them. Also we have a substantial number of customers running TinyMCE off our cloud, thus always running the latest version. If they do custom styling like this, TinyMCE might break for them without warning, and we cannot have that.

If you know what you are doing, I suggest investigating CSS pseudo class selectors like `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()`

Comment: I have control over HTML and CSS being used on the page. I would give it an unique classname in order not to let it interfere with other CSS. If I could inject the menu item with a span with some style on it - that could work as well. Pseudo selectors will not work in my case. I am making custom menu items that I want styled. Third party developers can choose to use them and also choose where they want them in the menu. I think I will have to resort to use the title attribute as a means of styling the menu items. Which I find quite a dirty way to make this work.

Comment: Here is an update to the fiddle where I use the title for styling purposes: https://jsfiddle.net/3ojvtr70/

Comment: I have no doubt you would make it work. But unfortunately we encounter people who dont. I'm sure you can see all the ways people would get creative if we supported setting a custom class or ID. I know I would. And then people get angry at us because they have to do work to upgrade TinyMCE, or they don't upgrade TinyMCE at all and miss out on bugfixes, security fixes and new features.
As a designer, I totally get the usefulness of being able to style individual buttons and menu items. But we haven't yet found a robust way to do that in a way that scales.